# For loop using a counter to then reset the loop with a different set of criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to make a for loop that has a set of criteria to move through the columns on an excel sheet replacing data, but I want to use a counter to signify when I want new criteria to enter the for loop. I also would like the for loop to fully exit when final criteria are met.

Thank you for any help!

I attempted to add a counter that would allow me to change criteria at set intervals of the loop.

```
Sub PayRollCleans()
    Dim i As Long, icount As Long
    Dim ilastrow As Long
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

    Set wsFrom = Sheets("Model Sheet")
    Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet1")
    ilastrow = wsFrom.Range("C100000:Z100000").End(xlUp).Row

    icount = 1
    WsFromColNumCrnt = 3
    WsToColNumCrnt = 1
    Count = 0
    X = 11

    For i = X To ilastrow Step 22
    
        wsTo.Cells(icount, WsToColNumCrnt) = wsFrom.Cells(i, WsFromColNumCrnt)
        WsToColNumCrnt = WsToColNumCrnt + 1
        Count = Count + 1
        
        If Count = 70 Then      
    
            icount = icount + 1
            WsFromColNumCrnt = WsFromColNumCrnt + 1
            X = X
            Count = 0
            If WsFromColNumCrnt = 26 Then Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can accomplish your goal without the use of multiple counters by utilizing what we have better. We can use the [`Modulo Operator (Mod)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/mod-operator), which gives the remainder of a division, instead of resetting `Count`. I also renamed your variables because using `i`, `count`, and `iCount` is really confusing.

```
Sub PayRollCleans()
    Dim toRowCounter as Long, toColCounter as Long
    Dim fromRowCounter as Long, fromColCounter as Long 
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet

    Set wsFrom = Sheets("Model Sheet")
    Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = wsFrom.Range("C100000:Z100000").End(xlUp).Row

    toRowCounter = 1
    fromColCounter = 3
    toColCounter = 1

    For fromRowCounter = 11 To lastrow Step 22
        If fromColCounter = 26 Then Exit For

        wsTo.Cells(toRowCounter, toColCounter) = wsFrom.Cells(fromRowCounter, fromColCounter)
        toColCounter = toColCounter + 1

        If (toColCounter - 1) Mod 70 = 0 Then      
            toRowCounter = toRowCounter + 1
            fromColCounter = fromColCounter + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This could probably be further improved. There's nothing incorrect about the `For` loop criteria but it's a bit nonstandard. Usually you'd use `For i = 1 to n` and then transform it to apply to the other criteria in the loop body:`fromFromCounter = 11 + i*22`.

Comment: Thank you for your edits to the code. However, the code is still only returning the data from column 3, C, of the wsFrom to  Row 1 of the wsTo. I am hoping to make this work so that after it completes 3, it then moves to 4,5, etc.

Comment: I see you posted an answer, did you figure out your problem? I assume that the issue was actually in the data you wanted to move around. Skipping 22 rows and only moving columns every 70 iterations means that you need a massive dataset to hit the `Exit For`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub PayRollCleans()
    Dim toRowCounter As Long, toColCounter As Long
    Dim fromRowCounter As Long, fromColCounter As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet
    
    Set wsFrom = Sheets("Model Sheet")
    Set wsTo = Sheets("Sheet1")
    lastRow = wsFrom.Range("C100000:AA100000").End(xlUp).Row
    
    toRowCounter = 1
    fromColCounter = 3
    toColCounter = 1
    X = 11
    
    For fromRowCounter = X To lastRow
        
        wsTo.Cells(toRowCounter, toColCounter) = wsFrom.Cells(X, fromColCounter)
        toColCounter = toColCounter + 1
        X = X + 22
        
        If toColCounter = 26 Then
            toRowCounter = toRowCounter + 1
            fromColCounter = fromColCounter + 1
            toColCounter = 1
            X = 11
            
            If fromColCounter = 60 Then Exit For
            
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```